# How to open .csf files?

Tags: windows

I downloaded some .csf file types, I cannot seem to be able to find a program capable of opening this format. Where would I be able to find a viewer for this file type?

Comment: what are they supposed to be? [link](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/csf)

Comment: just some lectures in C .

Comment: as in code or video? What type of file are they intended to be?

Comment: i really don't now , but it seems that they are in form of slides

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the [brava! reader](http://www.bravaviewer.com/download-brava-reader) for opening those [.csf](http://www.bravaviewer.com/csf) files

Comment: i've tried it before , it didn't work . i've read that these type of files are supported by adobe photoshop , but i'm not sure ?!

Comment: That would be a [color setting file](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/709569) not information like slides

Answer (score 0):

CSF file extension is associated with three types of files

1. Content Sealed Format
2. Adobe Color Settings File
3. Cal3D Binary Skeleton File

The most popular is second, you can open it using: Adobe Photoshop CC, Adobe InDesign CC, Adobe Illustrator CS6

You can look at the page like this, the list of programs can be updated: [CSF file](http://www.fileextension.org/CSF)